# How to delete tensors from pytorch graph?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I'm doing predictions on images for object detection in a for loop.
I've actually ran into the same issue with tensorflow and hoped I could solve it with pytorch.
At least now it seems I have found out what the issue is (naively assuming it's the same for tensorflow)

I predict like this

```
 model = detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True, 
    progress=True,pretrained_backbone=True).to(DEVICE)
    for i in tqdm(range(train.shape[0])):
        image = cv2.imread(train_img_paths[i])
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
        image = image / 255.0
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        image = torch.FloatTensor(image)
        image = image.to(DEVICE)
        predictions = model(image)[0]
```

Now through the garbage collector I found that each and every image stays in the graph.
Is there away to avoid it?

I have not been able to use dataloader or dataset with the detection models (same with tensorflow hub)

Comment: What are you doing with `predictions` after it is being defined?

Comment: Use `torch.from_numpy()` instead of `torch.FloatTensor()`

Comment: @Ivan predicions is a dictionary

Comment: @jhso I tried that in the beginning, it doesn't solve the issue, is it better practice? I'm new to torch.

Comment: It's optimised for numpy arrays. I'm also not sure if you need to set `model.eval()` and if you need to wrap your code with a `with torch.no_grad():`

Comment: @jhso I have model.eval() I have not tried with torch.no_grad() though I tried detaching in the loop. I'll try that now.

Comment: @jhso wrapping it got this: `RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.DoubleTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor)` should be the same edit: oh this may be rather because I used from_numpy()

Comment: That's because of torch.from_numpy. Cast the image to a float using `image = torch.from_numpy(image).float()`

Comment: @jhso thanks, it works now, I used astype(np.float32) before converting, is your way more preferable?

Comment: @jhso Apologies, it's become a lot better already, faster like crazy! memory doesn't increase as much anymore, but still linearly but about 20x less, any other tricks? :-)

Comment: @jhso I think you may add your comment as answer, it plataeud now at about 5gb of memory and hasn't been increasing, your solution (toch.no_grad) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget when you're doing testing to turn gradient accumulation off. You can do this by either wrapping your code like:

```
with torch.no_grad():
     model.eval()
     out = model(x)
```

or if your code is a function, using a decorator to do the same thing:

```
@torch.no_grad()
def model_proc(model,x):
    model.eval()
    return model(x)
```